# How does Tomcat on Mac OS X Server handle requests to different domain names?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mac-osx-server

I'm setting up a Mac OS X Server (10.5) machine, and that will include setting up Tomcat. The machine will be the host for at least two different domain names -- let's say myapp.example.com and myapp.anotherexample.com -- each of which will need to be hooked up to a different servlet. In other words, HTTP requests to http://myapp.example.com/ should get routed to the myappexample servlet, and HTTP requests to http://myapp.anotherexample.com/ should get routed to the myappanotherexample servlet.

How do I do this?

(I noticed the "Enable Tomcat" checkbox in Server Admin/Web/Settings/General, but it's not clear what this magical button will do, nor if that button will help me solve the problem I have.)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to : http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html

-- Ram